# LU decomposition of large dense matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, openmp

I wanted to generate LU decomposition of large size dense matrices (N>10^7), the LU decomposition I'm currently using is based on [Adaptive Cross Approximation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4tReu45goapY2g4VG5IRlM3aWM/view?usp=sharing) and is taking very long time to execute for larger N, can anybody suggest few LU decomposition techniques that can be very well parallelised(using OpenMP) and take shorter period of time.

**Note:**

1. I write the code in C++ and make use of Xeon Processor(128 threads)
   and Eigen library.
2. The entries in the matrix are filled through a kernel function of
   form exp(-(x1-x2)^2).
3. Storage of matrix is not a problem, I'm working on Xeon processor and has enough memory and moreover, I'm not storing the full matrix and whenever  I need to find an entry in matrix, I use the kernel function and generate type-double number for that cell.

Comment: Link is broken. How do you even store a 10⁷ × 10⁷ matrix?

Comment: Unless you have a shared memory machine with 800TB of RAM, I doubt OpenMP will be of any use for you. Now, maybe you can consider using a (very large) cluster and the Scalapack function [`PDGETRF()`](http://netlib.org/scalapack/slug/node178.html)

Comment: @Gilles Yes, you are right I'm working on shared memory and want to use openmp for parallelisation.

Comment: You said you had a 10⁷x10⁷ matrix to work on. That is about 800TB of RAM to store it. How do you do that?

Comment: @Gilles I don't store the whole matrix anywhere, as mentioned I used a kernel function to generate the required cells of a matrix.

Comment: You should rather ask on [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you show some code. A working example?